# Database Design for tracking user flow

Tags: python, django, django-models, orm, generic-foreign-key

[image]
[image]

I want to design a user tracking system between different models. There is a Module table which is related to sections and sections are related to sub-sections. Each sub-section can relate to different independent tables. The independent tables store different items (slides, videos, texts) which the user can go through in a linear flow just like a Coursera course. The flow will be predetermined by us but can be changed by us. So, the linear flow between the sub-sections can't be hardcoded. I also need to keep track of the user's progress through these sub-sections.

**For Example:**

*A sub-section can point to game table where the user_info, game_score, game_completion_date_time will be stored or there might be case where the sub-section is pointing to slides table storing slide_text, slide_url and user_info.*

I want to keep track of changes in those table so what should be my approach. Below i have posted an image in which i am approaching to the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You might make a 'courseflows' table with the order being a sequence of comma-separated integers for ids in the proper order, then parse through that sequence when presenting sections to the user.  Add whatever other information you need, and a timestamp so that any new users are assigned the most recent flow.  By linking this, you can also preserve any user's flow in case you change it while users are halfway through.

I would also consider using different secondary tables to mark user completion of each module, section, and subsection instead of just one.